# Broadcasting error when forming numpy array with elements as two other numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, broadcast

I am trying to generate a numpy array with elements as two other numpy arrays, as below.

```py
W1b1 = np.zeros((256, 161))
W2b2 = np.zeros((256, 257))
Wx = np.array([W1b1, W2b2], dtype=np.object)
```

this gives an error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (256,161) into shape (256).
```

However, if I take entirely different dimensions for of W1b1 and W2b2 then I do not get an error, as below.

```
A1 = np.zeros((256, 161))
A2 = np.zeros((257, 257))
A3 = np.array([A1, A2], dtype=np.object)
```

I do not get what is wrong in the first code and why is numpy array trying to broadcast one of the input arrays.

I have tried on below versions (Python 2.7.6, Numpy 1.13.1) and (Python 3.6.4, Numpy 1.14.1).

Comment: Why not just `Wx = [W1b1, W2b2]`? There's no benefit to keeping dtype object arrays anyway.

Comment: If you _really_ want to do this, an empty array will stop NumPy from trying to broadcast on the first dimension. `np.array([W1b1, W2b2, np.array([])], dtype=object)`

Comment: It is documented as a bug of sorts here: [Inconsistent behaviour of numpy.asarray on list of arrays #7453](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7453)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't count on `np.array(..., object)` making the right object array.  At the moment we don't have control over how many dimensions it makes.  Conceivably it could make a (2,) array, or (2, 256) (with 1d contents).  Sometimes it works, sometimes raises an error.  There's something of a pattern, but I haven't seen an analysis of the code that shows exactly what is happening.

For now it is safer to allocate the array, and fill it:

```
In [57]: arr = np.empty(2, object)
In [58]: arr[:] = [W1b1, W2b2]
```

`np.array([np.zeros((3,2)),np.ones((3,4))], object)` also raises this error.  So the error arises when the first dimensions match, but the later ones don't.  Now that I think about, I've seen this error before.

Earlier SO questions on the topic

[numpy array 1.9.2 getting ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,2) into shape (4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909619/numpy-array-1-9-2-getting-valueerror-could-not-broadcast-input-array-from-shape)

[Creation of array of arrays fails, when first size of first dimension matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511025/creation-of-array-of-arrays-fails-when-first-size-of-first-dimension-matches)

[Creating array of arrays in numpy with different dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117632/creating-array-of-arrays-in-numpy-with-different-dimensions)

Comment: It is suggested by user miradulo that this is possibly a bug. If you could elaborate if this a bug or expected feature of numpy. This will make the answer more complete.

Comment: This an edge case whose behavior changed around version 1.9, and may change in the future.  I haven't followed the relevant `issues` discussion.  Keep in mind that the basic `numpy` array is multidimensional with numeric or structured `dtype`.  Object dtype is a generalization that makes the array more list-like.  The desired behavior for cases like yours is not well defined.